# Custom keyboard for mathematical input

Tags: ios

How can you display a keyboard that has only digits and typical mathematical signs: parenthesis, operators `(+,*,/,-,^)`, etc..  I'm looking for something with the same look and feel as the standard keyboard on iOS, that can be moved, undocked,  and split. I could probably use buttons in a UIView but it wouldn't feel the same as the usual keyboard.

Comment: @MicRO double negatives confuse me.

Comment: Two "not's" in one sentence makes the logic 'interesting' to decipher

Comment: @KevinDTimm Especially when there are occurences of 'any', 'most', 'never', or colors.

Comment: "Is your question solved yet?" is the easiest :)

Comment: It looks more like a hack than a solution. I want to setup the complete layout of my keyboard

Comment: Here is an article that explains how to do it: http://blog.carbonfive.com/2012/03/12/customizing-the-ios-keyboard/

Answer (score 0):

## UIKeyboardType

```
The type of keyboard to display for a given text-based view.

typedef enum {
   UIKeyboardTypeDefault,
   UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable,
   UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation,
   UIKeyboardTypeURL,
   UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad,
   UIKeyboardTypePhonePad,
   UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad,
   UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress,
   UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad,
   UIKeyboardTypeTwitter,
   UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet = UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable
} UIKeyboardType;
```

**Set it as per your requirement.**